# POSTing from an Android Application

Tags: java, android, http, post

I'm currently attempting to write an Android Application which quite simply POSTs data to a server on button press.

I've followed other posts on here to attempt to get this working but it doesn't want to play ball. I just seem to be wrestling with Android Studio and the java language at the minute, which is a shame because I want to like java. POSTing is so simple in other languages.

When I fire up Wireshark and press the button on the application, I can see packets coming through on port 80, although there is no application layer data.

Please see the code for my httpHelper class below. It's basically adapted from the example provided in the Complete Reference (9th Edition) book (used for GET request) and then adapted to POST with the information I gathered from Stack Overflow:

```
public class httpHelper {
String url;
public httpHelper(String hturl){
    url = hturl;
}
//Literally no idea why this isn't working.
void postData(String qString) throws Exception{
    URL hp = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();
    hpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    hpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    hpCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hpCon.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
    hpCon.setDoInput(true);
    hpCon.setUseCaches(false);
    byte[] postString = qString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    hpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postString.length));
    try{
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( hpCon.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postString);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: You can check if there is an exception (you're just printing a stacktrace you can rethrow it for debugging). And check the connection status which should be 200

Comment: Then there are libraries like OkHttp (and a more high-level Retrofit) which spare you from all of that

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley library for networking. Reduces the burden by a huge factor. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/mombrea/7250835) an example.